# Win+[key] hotkey sending a Win+[key] combo unreliable in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

This simple code sometimes works and sometimes does not: `#F1::#1` Sometimes it switches to the first app on the taskbar, sometimes it just types a 1. Why might that be?

The code I'm working on is:

```
#f2::
sleep 1000
Send {LWin down}
Loop 3
{
    Send 1  
    Sleep 100 
}
Send {LWin up}
Return
```

This switches to the third window of the first app on the taskbar. The `sleep 1000` delays it too much to be of use to me, but if I omit it, or even change it to just `sleep 100`, it (usually?) doesn't work. I wonder if when I release the windows key it interprets it as a key-up before I get to send the <kbd>1</kbd>, but it happens when I use trigger it by typing  <kbd>RWin</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> too. I tried replacing the sleep with `KeyWait, LWin`, but that didn't help.

This seems like a simple question but I can't find anything about it. I tried using ~ and $ and {blind} and InputLevel, but none of them worked.

Comment: This works fine here: `#f2::Send {LWin down}111{LWin up}`

Comment: @Relax Interesting, yes it does. I wonder what the difference is. Unfortunately without the sleep in between the 1s it isn't reliable. I'll try it and it will get stuck sometimes, I can't figure out what conditions make it get stuck. But it is definitely not typing 1s, so at least that problem is fixed...

Answer (score 0):

`#F1::#1` isn't reliable.

[Remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Remap.htm) doesn't release the modifier keys, because it uses the [blind](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Blind) mode.

Use the Send command instead:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#f1::Send #1
#f2::Send {LWin down}111{LWin up}
```